# generating an automated electrical network in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to create an automatically generated network in MATLAB. To achieve this, I plan to utilize the incidence matrix, which will be generated automatically. I will only need to specify the length of a single edge. The network should represent a finite grid of resistors with a reference node. What I want to achieve is to get all node voltages and plot them.

This is my code so far:

```
% Network Size
n = 49; % Grid side length

% Resistance Value
R = 100; % Resistance value

% Choose the side for injection (1 = top, 2 = right, 3 = bottom, 4 = left)
sourceSide = 3; % Injection from the bottom

% Number of Nodes and Edges
numNodes = n^2;
numEdges = n*(n-1);

% Create the Incidence Matrix (Example for a grid network)
incidenceMatrix = zeros(numEdges, numNodes);

for i = 1:numNodes
% Top
if i > n
    incidenceMatrix(i - n, i) = -1;
    incidenceMatrix(i, i) = 1;
end

% Left
if mod(i, n) ~= 1
    incidenceMatrix((n-1) * (i-1) + (i - mod(i, n)), i) = -1;
    incidenceMatrix((n-1) * (i-1) + (i - mod(i, n)) + 1, i) = 1;
end
end

% Create Network Equations
A = [incidenceMatrix; zeros(numNodes, numNodes)];
b = zeros(numEdges + numNodes, 1);

% Choose the injected node based on the selected side
if sourceSide == 1 % Top
sourceNode = ceil(n/2);
elseif sourceSide == 2 % Right
sourceNode = n * ceil(n/2);
elseif sourceSide == 3 % Bottom
sourceNode = numNodes - ceil(n/2) + 1;
elseif sourceSide == 4 % Left
sourceNode = n * floor(n/2) + 1;
end

% Set the injected current
b(numEdges + sourceNode) = 1;

% Calculate Edge Resistances
edgeResistances = ones(numEdges + numNodes, 1) * R;

% Calculate Node Potentials
nodePotentials = A \ (edgeResistances .* b);

% Plot Node Potentials
figure;
imshow(reshape(nodePotentials, n, n), []);
title('Node Potentials');
colormap(jet);
colorbar;
```

How can I calculate the incidence matrix?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. You calculate the `incidenceMatrix` right there. Why does this not suffice? Also, what is an "incidence matrix"?

Comment: an incidence matrix of a network graph is a matrix that shows the relationships of arcs and nodes. Normally the columns are the arcs and the rows the nodes. The element can have 3 values, 1 for outgoing arcs, -1 for ingoing arcs, 0 for branches neither ingoing or outgoing

Comment: This code does not run correctly in any case, regardless of the incidenceMatrix query. When you calculate nodePotentials the dimensions of the 2 matrixes don't agree (tetsed with n=5 and n=8)